# Adding "Perform Maven Release" option from Jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, release, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to make the Perform Maven Release option visible under the job created using Jenkinsfile? I have a job that is created manually and it has this option set by selecting the Maven release build option in Configure job->Build environment settings. I am trying to convert this manual job to pipeline job using Jenkinsfile.

Comment: all I could tell so far is "not from the Jenkinsfile only" i.e. it may need a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you had requested, but it should provide the closest equivalent.  It will start a timer to ask for a release and if not it will terminate the build successfully.

```
node {
    // Environment setup
    mvnHome = tool name:'maven-3.3.9', type: 'maven'
    env.PATH = "${mvnHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"

    stage("Checkout") {
        checkout scm
    }

    stage("Build SNAPSHOT") {
        mvn 'deploy site'
    }
    boolean release = false
    stage("Release confirmation") {
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES') {
            input 'Release to Central?'
            release = true
        }
    }
    if (release) {
        stage("Release") {
            mvn 'release:prepare'
            mvn 'release:perform'
        } 
    }
}
@NonCPS
def mvn(String args) {
    sh "mvn --batch-mode ${args}"
}
```